# How to set time format hh:mm:ss for textbox in html5

Tags: html

how to set textbox format HH:MM:SS in html5. The current format showing only
hours and minutes. I want seconds also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a step of `1` second to make seconds count:

```html
<input type="time" step="1">
```

If you want a better look than `--:--:--`, you can set an initial value of `00:00:00`:

```html
<input value="00:00:00" type="time" step="1">
```